# Creating front-end user interactive table using MySQL as back-end

Tags: java, swing

Creating front-end (Java) user interactive table using MySQL as back-end

Now im trying to create user interactive form.
Untill now, I have created a form view, using swing components, JLable, JTextfield where user enters data. JButtons, 'new' 'save' 'delete' 'edit', which listens user action through ActionListner.

A table that 'extends' AbstractTableModel. Table values are the ResultSet values. i have used MySQL connectivity.
Table is displayed. User can now add new row to it, using 'New' and 'Save' button.

My problem is, i need the corresponding TextFields to display the corresponding row user selects in the displayed table, so that 'edit' and 'delete' would be user interactive. users are allowed to select table's row. Need Help.
Im sorry if any mistake in my question format and language. Thank you!

i need code for creating table  ...
ple help me on tis....

Comment: -1, try reading up JDBC and write code. Ask a question if you have specific question instead of asking for full program

Comment: I found the jgoodies binding API useful to bind data to a datagrid

Comment: i have done with add and retriving mytable from database ... now in that table i have created delete and edit button i dont know what ActionListner how to use tat to make data delete in my databse.

Answer (score 2):

> *i need code for creating table*

How much will you pay? :)

> *..i need the corresponding TextFields to display the corresponding row user selects in the displayed table..*

For that you can use,

1. Give a button, like <kbd>EDIT</kbd> and in the event handler for <kbd>EDIT</kbd> use something like,

   ```
   jTextField.setText( jTable.getValueAt(
                                          jTable.getSelectedRow(),   
                                          jTable.getSelectedColumn())
                                          .toString()
                      );
   ```

2.As an alternative you can also utilize the event in jtable like `mouseClicked` with the above code

---

Now regarding the `edit` and `delete` , you may utilize the `focusLost` event of the textfield or use a <kbd>EDIT</kbd> or <kbd>DELETE</kbd> button, and carryout the updation, which will be much reasonable option.

---

Additionaly have a look at this : [Using JDBC with GUI API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcswing.html)